# PHP: Curl_exec not returning result properly

Tags: php, curl, utf-8, character-encoding, byte-order-mark

I'm trying to download a web page using the following code:

```
function request($url){
    $curl_timeout = 5;
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $curl_timeout);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    $res = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $res;
}
echo request('http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=15');
```

This code prints something like: 
`�"X��}koǵ�� ����n2��٬����'�º׈���1$[��#��H���������RQ,+���k��`
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this to your curl instance.
`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");`

And you should be fine, read more here (http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)